# PHP copy() function not working with list of items from txt file

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a txt file that contains about 400 urls to images(excerpt below). I wrote the below script to quickly download the files from one server to another (no ssh access).

Text File - pics.txt

```
http://www.domain.com/pictures/name.jpg
http://www.domain.com/pictures/name1.jpg
http://www.domain.com/pictures/name2.jpg
http://www.domain.com/pictures/name3.jpg
http://www.domain.com/pictures/name4.jpg
```

My simple PHP Script:

```
$file = fopen("pics.txt", "r");

while(!feof($file)){

    $line = fgets($file);
    $filename = basename($line);
    $imagename = "tmp/$filename";
    echo "Trying to copy ".$line." to: ".$imagename;

    if (copy($line,$imagename)) {
        echo "Done file ".$line;
    } else {
        echo "Error occured";
    }

}
fclose($file);
```

However it doesn't seem to work. I just get:

```
Trying to copy http://www.domain.com/pictures/name.jpg to: tmp/name.jpg Error occured
Trying to copy http://www.domain.com/pictures/name1.jpg to: tmp/name1.jpg Error occured
Trying to copy http://www.domain.com/pictures/name2.jpg to: tmp/name2.jpg Error occured
```

If I manually type the `copy('http://www.domain.com/pictures/name.jpg', 'filename.jpg');`

it works fine?

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just commented everything out and put a line in the php file..

Comment: make sure that folder has proper permissions to write to it and the path is correct and exists. Use error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: but it works when I hardcode the copy line in instead of doing it dynamically.. I CHMOD 777 the tmp directory to test.

Comment: error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php `echo "Error occured";` you're not gettting the real error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, and for future readers to the question as to what the problem really was.

Your file contains `\n` for each line and is a hidden file character, adding a space to your URL, in turn breaking it's true path.

Using `trim()` will get rid of the extra spaces.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Use error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

From comments:

> *"Thanks both, I turned on the error reporting and noticed it was putting a space after the url, even though there isnt one in the text file. – Chris"*

and

> *"@Chris that's great Chris (you're welcome) and I'm glad that it was resolved. However and for future readers to the question, the answer given really wasn't the solution. I don't want to sound as the bad man here or bust everybody's balloon; don't get me wrong. However, that being the case, you should have used `trim()` to get rid of the trailing spaces. The spaces come from the hidden `\n` in the file which adds a space. – Fred -ii-"*

Comment: Thanks Fred! All sorted :-)

Comment: @Chris You're very much welcome Chris. I'm glad that we were able to pinpoint the exact cause, *cheers*